# How do I remove a connect-flash message?

Tags: javascript, html, express, logout

I want to remove a message(with the username after a login) when I press the logout button. When I try to press the logout button nothing happens just refreshes the page. I want to remain on the same page and not redirect to a different page. Should I change  the logout button type to submit?

html code:

```
<body>
    <p id="after"><%= username %></p>
    <div class="login">
      <h1>Login</h1>
      <form action="/" method="post">
        <label for="username">
          <!-- font awesome icon -->
          <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
        </label>
        <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" required />
        <label for="password">
          <i class="fas fa-lock"></i>
        </label>
        <input
          type="password"
          name="password"
          placeholder="Password"
          id="password"
          required
        />
        <input type="submit" value="Login" />
        <button id="logout" name="logout" type="button">Logout</button>
      </form>
```

JS CODE

```
 app.get("/", function (req, res) {
  const username = req.flash("user");
  res.render("login", { username });
});

app.post("/", function (request, response) {
  // Capture the input fields

  let username = request.body.username;
  let password = request.body.password;
  // Ensure the input fields exists and are not empty
  if (username && password) {
    // Execute SQL query that'll select the account from the database based on the specified username and password
    connection.query(
      "SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE username = ? AND password = ?",
      [username, password],
      function (error, results, fields, name) {
        // If there is an issue with the query, output the error
        if (error) throw error;
        // If the account exists
        if (results.length > 0) {
          
          request.session.loggedin = true;
          request.session.username = username;

        

          request.flash("user", request.body.username);

          response.redirect("/");
        } else {
          response.send("Incorrect Username and/or Password!");
        }
        response.end();
      }
    );
  } else {
    response.send("Please enter Username and Password!");
    response.end();
  }
    //try to logout
  app.get("/", async (request, response) => {
    if (request.flash.username) {
      delete request.flash.username;
      response.json({ result: "SUCCESS" });
    } else {
      response.json({ result: "ERROR", message: "baba" });
    }
  });
});

app.listen(port);
console.log(`Server is listening on port ${port}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
you can remove the message from req ,before rendering the page :
const myUser=flash("usrID","username");
......
flash("usrID","");
and check it on frontend.  for example,if frontend is EJS:

 <% if ( myUser.length!==0 ) { %> //other condition is needed
    .............
    .............              
 <% } %>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your answer. Please provide more details about your solution. Code snippets, high quality descriptions, or any relevant information would be great. Clear and concise answers are more helpful and easier to understand for everyone. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77045362/edit) your answer with specifics to raise the quality of your answer. For more information: [How To: Write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Happy coding!